# Are long-stay visas in France multi-entry by default?

Tags: schengen, france, long-stay-visas

I am an US citizen and planning to go to France for a year for tourism/personal reasons. I expect to be issued a [long-stay visa](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/web/france-visas/visa-de-long-sejour) (VLS-TS or perhaps VLS-T, not sure how they determine this). My question is, if I want to go home (to the US) for, say, a week during Christmastime, would I normally be allowed back into France? Similarly, if I wish to visit the UK for a weekend, would I be able to return to France with the default long-stay visa?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is either a Double-entry Schengen Visa, or a Multiple-entry Schengen Visa. Those would allow you to go outside the Schengen Area, and come back (either once, with the Double-entry, or multiple times)

Comment: Yes, D visa is generally multi-entry... But tourism is usually not a sufficient reason to have a long-stay visa.

Comment: @xngtng it is in France: see https://www.welcometofrance.com/en/sheet/fact-sheet-long-stay-visa and https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2651

Comment: Thank you all! I am actually doing a mix of tourism and volunteering, but the French visa wizard says I would have to agree "to leave the French territory at the end of the volunteer contract," when I would want to stay for an additional few months for tourism, which is why I am applying for a tourist visa instead.

Comment: The information I find on welcometofrance.com seems to indicate that the visa is either equivalent to a temporary residence permit, or allows you to obtain one. With a residence permit you can leave the country and return, as long as you do not stay abroad for too long.